# prolog term to string

Tags: string, prolog

i have a prolog list like this:

```
[p(X,Y,Z),r(H,G,K)]
```

and i want convert it
into this:

```
'p(X,Y,Z)r(H,G,K)'
```

it is just a list of predicate, that should be transformed into a string.

Do you have any idea? ( I use prolog)

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? Where do you "have" the original list? In a textfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think doing that is not possible. After you declare a variable, its name is lost for further processing.

**EDIT:**

Something like this is possible, if you don't mind losing the names. At least in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- format(atom(A), "~w~w", [p(X,Y,Z),r(H,G,K)]).
A = 'p(_G924,_G925,_G926)r(_G931,_G932,_G933)'.
```

Comment: guys you are really sure of this?

Comment: there isn't a way to add ' to the being of the variable and ' in the end like a string manipulation?

Comment: Like I said, you have the list, you don't actually have the variable names. You can't modify something you don't have.

Comment: That's almost like trying extract names from [p(_,_,_),r(_,_,_)]. Also strictly speaking Prolog does not have variables

Comment: ok i believe you , we wait if someone have an idea. i saw a prolog called Eclipse-prolog which have this function but the site is in japanese and i don't understand nothing.. wait i link you

Comment: http://www.win.tue.nl/~setalle/lp/eclipse-doc/bips/kernel/termmanip/term_string-2.html

Answer (score 1):

You can read terms using the `variable_names` option, which gives you a list of *Name=Variable* pairs in the read term. So maybe this is what you need.

Here is a command line that reads the term, then unifies the variables with their names and finally prints the result into an atom in the way that you specified in your question.

```
?- read_term(Term, [variable_names(VarNames)]), maplist(call, VarNames),
                                with_output_to(atom(Atom), maplist(write, Term)).
|: [p(X,Y,Z),r(H,G,K)].
Term = [p('X', 'Y', 'Z'), r('H', 'G', 'K')],
VarNames = ['X'='X', 'Y'='Y', 'Z'='Z', 'H'='H', 'G'='G', 'K'='K'],
Atom = 'p(X,Y,Z)r(H,G,K)'.
```

Note that it modifies the read term, so you might want to make a copy of it first (`copy_term/2`).